# Finding global minimum of complicated nonlinear function within the range of Earth's surface (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, minimum, coordinate-transformation, nonlinear-functions, function-handle

I am struggling with finding the global (or at least local minimum) of nonlinear 3-variable function **S(t,x,y)** defined as following with MATLAB 2016b:

[image]

Given function requires **x_i, y_i, d_i, v** as input variables and **x, y, t** are variables to be actually changed in certain range.

I found out that the MATLAB function **fminsearch** is quite useful when finding the local minimum, but I couldn't find the solution to find global minimum of such complicated function in the web.

The range of **(x, y)** is the every coordinate in the surface of Earth and **t** varies within short interval with the gap of approximately 100. Also, the function **S** is designed to take the input variables as Cartesian coordinates, not latitudes or longitudes.

I have another relevant question. Actually I have variables **x_i, y_i** as the form of latitudes and longitudes, not Cartesian coordinates. Thus, it is necessary that I should change those locations to Cartesian coordinates. Since four locations are concentrated in narrow region (within the latitude and longitude range less than 1 degree), I want to convert them to the Cartesian coordinates in plane by approximating that curvature is almost 0. However, I find it difficult because of lack of geometrical ability. Thus, I would be appreciated if someone could help me with this problem as well.

The following are four locations with latitudes and longitudes which I should input in S:

```
[lat_1, long_1]=(40.326800,-124.949200),
[lat_2, long_2]=(40.381200,-124.785300),
[lat_3, long_3]=(40.438700, -124.808500),
[lat_4, long_4]=(40.495500, -124.591800)
```

Currently, I wrote the function **S** in **function_handle** form like the following:

```
S=@(x)(((x(1)+sqrt((x(2)-m1(2,1))^2+(x(3)-m1(3,1))^2)/v)-m1(1,1))^2+((x(1)+sqrt((x(2)-m2(2,1))^2+(x(3)-m2(3,1))^2)/v)-m2(1,1))^2+((x(1)+sqrt((x(2)-m3(2,1))^2+(x(3)-m3(3,1))^2)/v)-m3(1,1))^2+((x(1)+sqrt((x(2)-m4(2,1))^2+(x(3)-m4(3,1))^2)/v)-m4(1,1))^2);
```

where **m1,m2,m3,m4** are column vectors in the form of **(t,x,y)**

Comment: Finding local minima is "easy", finding global minima of a non-convex/non-linear function is still an open problem in mathematics.

Comment: @AnderBiguri In my case, domain is constrained so it seems that searching for every point might be the solution (i.e. **Grid Search**). But I cannot get an idea of  how to this.